# Text file data into python list

Tags: python, list, file, loops, text

I have a text file of 1000 float data (vertically arranged, in 1000 lines), I need to insert that data into one single List. I can't seem to be able to manage the right code for it.

```
0.600250005722
0.601000022888
0.601000022888
0.601875019073
0.602374982834
0.601875019073
```

I need them as

```
list_var=[0.600250005722,0.601000022888,0.601000022888,0.601875019073,0.602374982834,0.601875019073]
```

Can someone please help me with the correct code.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a simple case of `open().readlines()`? Have you read any python tutorials at all? You'll also get more help if you show your efforts, instead of asking for "gimme the codez". And it's also hard for someone to "help" you with the code if they don't know what you're struggling with.

Comment: f = open("C:\Python27\shot_files\kw200_cg_c.txt", 'r')
for line in f:
    data = [line.strip()]
print data

Comment: .readline() reads only 1 line at a time, that is definitely NOT what I want. I want to append the entire data into one list only. As float data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want your output to be a float value.

```
list_var = open("small_list.txt", "r").read().split()
new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(list_var)):
    new_list.append(float(list_var[i]))

print(new_list)
```

The `print(new_list)` line is just to display that it´s indeed float.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Actually I am supposed to use this list to insert data into a Tree Signal node of MDSplus Data Acquisition Tree storage system. And then use this 1000 data (as I mentioned earlier) to produce a Signal and view it on jScope as a graph for Signal visualization against time.

Answer (score -2):

Do this

```
lst = open('filename', 'r').read().split()
```

This opens a file, converts it to a string and splits it whenever it encounters a '\n' and stores the result as a list.